# Imageview left and right white space issue

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-imageview, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to set 1080*1920 image in imageview but it showing white space left and right side. It showing same in all device having resolution of 480*800,720*1280,768*1280,1080*1920,1440*2560. Please check attached image Also, i tried to set  **android:adjustViewBounds="true"** but it didn't work if i set **android:scaleType="fitXY"** image is streched. Please help me with some solution as i'm trying all possible way but not worked till now.
  [image]

```
This is xml layout code :
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_gallery1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/atest"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" --> iF i use fitXY then image is streched
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout xml

Comment: Post your *xml* code. and that image which you are trying to show.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

or:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

also make sure whichever container you have the imageview inside is able to fill the full screen.

Comment: Please check my xml layout code. I edited in question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The resolution you mentioned i.e 1920x1080 is ideally a landscape resolution.

So if you intend to put the image in portrait mode, then try changing the resolution of image to 1080x1920.

Also, as Philip said, make sure the imageview's container is able to fill the screen.

Comment: Hi @Jubin Mathai, Image resolution is 1080*1920 and it's portrait size